# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for a repository in a library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created a library for sharing code over multiple Spring Boot applications.

The library contains a Repository class `RequestRepository`. After adding the library to the Spring Boot project, it compiles and runs unit tests successful.

```
// Library: RequestRepository.java
package org.test.lib;

public interface RequestRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, Integer> {}

// Application: Application.java
package org.test.app;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.test.app", "org.test.lib"})
public class Application {
  // ...
}
```

Starting the application raises a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when Spring tries to autowire the repository.

> Caused by:
>   `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`: No
>   qualifying bean of type '`org.test.lib.repositories.RequestRepository`'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I enabled DEBUG logging for the component scan and got the following output regarding the repository.

> 2018-07-10 08:33:25.035 DEBUG 14976 --- [           main]
>   .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Resolved location pattern
>   [classpath*:org/test/lib/**/*.class] to resources [URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/.../lib-request-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/test/lib/repositories/RequestRepository.class],
>   ...

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Did you autowire your `RequestRepository` in the class where you use it?

Comment: @TA I try to keep my question short. The code of the lib/app worked in a single Spring Boot project. What are you looking for?

Comment: I am missing the class where you actually call your repository. Without any context this is hard to solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable the repositories outside of your Spring Boot application with `@EnableJpaRepositories` explicitly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.test.app", "org.test.lib"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.test.app", "org.test.lib"})
public class Application {
  // ...
}
```

See [Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa).

> By default, Spring Boot will enable JPA repository support and look in
>   the package (and its subpackages) where `@SpringBootApplication` is
>   located. If your configuration has JPA repository interface
>   definitions located in a package not visible, you can point out
>   alternate packages using `@EnableJpaRepositories` and its type-safe
>   `basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class` parameter.

For using `@Entity` classes from the library set `@EntityScan`.