# Sprin Boot: Repository bean not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm building applications that could use the same entities and repository classes. So I create a lib with these objects and installed it in Maven and included a dependency in `pom.xml` in the new project. However, when I call the page the error below appears.

The lib contains the configuration DB class and in the all declaration of the service in the new project's controller I use the annotation `@Autowired`. Tomcat does not show any problem on start.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-02 09:54:53.546 ERROR 20368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in br.com.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'br.com.repository.PersonRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.com.repository.PersonRepository' in your configuration.
```

**EDIT:**

Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "br.com.*" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.*" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.*"})
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

POM.XML with my lib with the commons objects:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>br.com</groupId>
     <artifactId>objetos.base</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Lib Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface  PersonRepository  extends CassandraRepository<Person, UUID>{
```

Lib Service:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: You are not defining/importing any `PersonRepository`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258828/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-for-a-repository-in-a-library).

Comment: Hi, I defining/importing. I'm using @EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.*" }) in the @SpringBootApplication. In the pom.xml, the lib dependency with this commons object that I created. I edited the question for you see.

Comment: Is `PersonRepository` annotaded with `@Repository`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm trying to reuse some repository classes as a lib.

Comment: One thing I can think of right now (as a workaround) is to create an Interface implementing the repository of your library and annotating it with @Repository.  This pretty much does what the log asks you to do, but I'm guessing this is not the way you wanted implemented, right?.

Comment: yes, is not the way I wanted implemented, but I'll try it. I wanted to avoid refactoring the same code in severals project. They are the same, so I  created a project with them and install as a lib in all project that it'll need.

Comment: have you tried naming the package without the wildcard?  `@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.repository" } )`  or simply `@EnableCassandraRepositories("br.com.repository")`

Comment: Could you post the `@Repository` and `@Service` definitions?

Comment: @HopeyOne, I did the both alternatives. The error persist. I think the spring boot is not recognize that the others repositories are in a lib. The package name is the same, but it's not recognize.

Comment: Your implementation seems to me correct. I tried to reproduce your use case, and all run well. What version of `spring-boot` are you using?

Comment: @thepaoloboi, thanks! This application use version 2.4.2 .

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Just looking at some [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial), do you need to provide a configuration class bases on `AbstractCassandraConfiguration`?

Comment: @HopeyOne, thanks! I have one application running well using AbstractCassandraConfiguration. The problem is when I tried to separed some commom reposytory/service in a jar file to be use in another application.